# QPlainTextEdit Restrict char

Tags: c++, qt

I am using using QPlainTextEdit in Qt as a field entry. Is there a way to restrict or ignore specific characters?

For example, I would like to disregard the enter key (`\n` or `\r\n` depending on platform).

Comment: The `\n` and `\r\n` are not keys, they are the text inserted upon a keypress. One way of ignoring certain keystrokes is to install an event filter. Of course your users still can paste newlines in. Thus you should filter the text after the entry is finished, too. And you should ask yourself whether you really want to remove line endings. It seems to me you want a `QLineEdit` instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting it up to regex after each `textChanged()` event, I read the comment from @Kuba Ober above. Yes, the simple answer is that I forgot about `QLineEdit`, which has exactly the behavior I was looking for!

Comment: Note that you *can* paste newlines into a `QLineEdit`, so if your other code can't cope with them, you must remove them from the value you get from `text()`. OTOH, ask yourself this: is the limitation absolutely necessary? Sometimes it is. Yet I know of a few pieces of software where the code that uses the text knows how to render line breaks, but the control is single-lined, and the only way to work around it is to copy-paste text with newlines from e.g. notepad. These applications would be much less functional without this workaround. So don't discount a `QPlainTextEdit` outright.

Comment: For this situation, it is simply used as an entry on a form that is matching the input to a JSON lookup on `textChanged`. I am finding that people are people instinctively pressing enter when they are _done_, but the newline breaks the matching. Simply restricting it solves the problem in this case. Good caveats though.

Comment: In your case then a `QLineEdit` is perfect *and* you probably should remove line breaks from `text()`, too, just so it doesn't become a vulnerability of some sort or doesn't expose bugs in code that doesn't expect newlines in such input.